# @RequestParam with Optional Spring REST

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I have a Spring REST endpoint with Optional request params like below:

```
public ResponseEntity<Product> globalProduct(@RequestParam Optional<Integer> id, @RequestParam Optional<String> name){

return ResponseEntity.ok(tm));
}
```

when I'm trying to test this endpoint which uses Mockito framework

```
@Test                                                                               
public void testGlobalProduct() throws Exception {                        
    URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromPath("/api/products")                  
            .queryParam("id", Optional.of(1)                                               
            .queryParam("name", Optional.empty())                                 
            .build().toUri();                                                       
    mockMvc.perform( MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(uri)                                
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))                                    
            .andExpect(status().isOk())                                             
            .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))           
            .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())                                   
            .andReturn();                                                           
}
```

So the queryParams id and name should be Optional.of(1) and Optional.empty() , but when I debug  in the rest api implementaion I see `id` and `name` has been wrapped with values `Optional[Optional[1]]` and `Optiona[Optional.empty]]` .

I know I can use @RequestParams(required=false) but I dont want to use that way in this context.

How do we unwrap `Optional[Optional[1]]` `Optiona[Optional.empty]]` Is this correct? Any suggestions please?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working. I put default value for param 'name'

```
public ResponseEntity<Product> globalProduct(@RequestParam Optional<Integer> id,  @RequestParam(value = "") Optional<String> name){

        return ResponseEntity.ok(tm));
   }
```

And I did not pass any requestParam from the test, so it defaults to empty. It works.

```
@Test                                                                               
public void testGlobalProduct() throws Exception {                        
    URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromPath("/api/products")                  
            .queryParam("id", Optional.of(1)                                               
            .build().toUri();                                                       
    mockMvc.perform( MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(uri)                                
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))                                    
            .andExpect(status().isOk())                                             
            .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))           
            .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())                                   
            .andReturn();                                                           
}
```

Thanks all for suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are passing an Optional in the query param which is again wrapped in an optional at controller layer. Try following and check.

```
@Test                                                                               
public void testGlobalProduct() throws Exception {                        
    URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromPath("/api/products")                  
            .queryParam("id", 1)                                                                               
            .build().toUri();                                                       
    mockMvc.perform( MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(uri)                                
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))                                    
            .andExpect(status().isOk())                                             
            .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))           
            .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())                                   
            .andReturn();                                                           
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response yes, I have tried passing .queryParam("id", 1)   it works but when I try to pass Optional.empty() for the queryParam "name" , the value that api end point recieves is Optional[Optional.empty[]]. when I check  something like `name.orElse("no value")`, when I debug the "name" always shows Optional[Optional.empty[] and it supposed to give "no value".  But it never consider orElse value which is "no value" .  Even If I use .queryParam("name", "") it never goes through orElse("no value").   Just wondering how would I pass empty value.

Comment: Don't pass the parameter if you want it to be empty. Empty means it isn't in the request.